# How to hide a specific class field?

Tags: css

I need to hide this field "estimated move-out date". How can I do it with CSS?

```
<p class="mphb_sc_search-check-out-date frm_form_field">
    <label for="mphb_check_out_date-mphb-search-form-5eb2a4b467b3b">
        Estimated move-out date         <abbr title="Formatted as dd/mm/yyyy">*</abbr>
    </label>
    <br>
    <input id="mphb_check_out_date-mphb-search-form-5eb2a4b467b3b" data-datepick-group="mphb-search-form-5eb2a4b467b3b" value="" placeholder="Estimated move-out date" required="required" type="text" name="mphb_check_out_date" class="mphb-datepick mphb_datepicker is-datepick" autocomplete="off">
</p>
```

So far I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
.mphb_sc_search-check-out-date frm_form_field { display: none; }
```

Tried also:

```
.mphb_sc_search-check-out-date.frm_form_field { visibility: hidden; }
```

Worked. Except it left a big blank hole in the middle. Not ideal but...

Finally I figured it out!

```
.mphb_sc_search-check-out-date.frm_form_field {
  display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried to solve your problem?

Comment: any code reference?

Comment: <p class="mphb_sc_search-check-out-date frm_form_field">
  <label for="mphb_check_out_date-mphb-search-form-5eb2a4b467b3b">
   Estimated move-out date   <abbr title="Formatted as dd/mm/yyyy">*</abbr>
  </label>
  <br>
  <input id="mphb_check_out_date-mphb-search-form-5eb2a4b467b3b" data-datepick-group="mphb-search-form-5eb2a4b467b3b" value="" placeholder="Estimated move-out date" required="required" type="text" name="mphb_check_out_date" class="mphb-datepick mphb_datepicker is-datepick" autocomplete="off">
 </p>

Comment: you could try ```.mphb_sc_search-check-out-date .frm_form_field { display: none; }```

Comment: Tried that:    .mphb_sc_search-check-out-date.frm_form_field {
  display: none;
}     Stiill not working. Could it be because I'm working with Elementor?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class and add it to the element.

.display-none { display:none; }

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work:    .mphb_sc_search-check-out-date frm_form_field { display: none; }

Comment: Try this : <p  style="display:none">